# Data Structure Representation of Specific Tree for Depth First Search in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, python-2.7, depth-first-search

I try to implement branch and bound with iterative depth-first search, but have no clue what is the best data structure representation? I'd like to calculate weight of each branch traverse from root to leave. If the branch value exceed max_weight, prune the branch, and backtrack to neighbour branch

Figure below shows a simple illustration of the tree.

```
                                          0
                           /                             \
                          /                               \ 
                        1 (X1=1)                           0 (X1=0)
                  /                     \              /               \
                 /                       \            /                 \
               1 (X2=1)             0 (X2=0)        1(X2=1)            0(X2=0)  
        /               \          /
       /                 \        /
   1 (X3=1)          0 (X3=0)  1 (X3=1)
```

The tree starts from

```
root 0 -> 
node X1=1 -> 
node X2=1 -> 
node X3=1 (calculate branch value)->
node X3=0 (calculate branch value)-> 
node X2 = 0-> 
node X3=1 (calculate branch value)->
node X1=0 ->
node X2=1 (calculate branch value)
node X2=0 (calculate branch value)
```

My question is, what is the best representation (list? dictionary?) for the node & edge?

For eg, example below shows a representation of tree with clear representation of each node

```
graph = {'A':['B','C'],'B':['D','E'],'C':['D','E'],'D':['E'],'E':['A']}`
```

But it seems that such representation is inappropriate in my case. Any suggestion?

Comment: What about your case makes a dictionary representation seems inappropriate? Is it because the same nodes have multiple parents?

Comment: there is no unique key right? X2=1 repeats twice, X3=1 repeats twice or more in some case.... the only unique is the binary value from root to each node (eg, (0,1,1,1), (0,1,1,0) etc), but the graph has to generate on the fly

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just give them different labels? For instance, A would represent the root, B would represent X1=1, C would represent X1=0, D would represent X2=1 when X1=1, E would be X2=0 when X1=1, F would be X2=1 when X1=0, G would be X2=0 with X1=0 and so on. Then they would each have a unique key and you could use the dictionary structure (which seems like the best option if you don't want to make your own node class).

Comment: If the different occurrences of the same key are so fundamentally the same that giving them different labels makes you uncomfortable, then I might question whether or not a tree is a valid way to formulate this problem in the first place.